# How to get User Object of Currently Logged User in Vue Component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am new to Laravel and Vue Js. I need to get the Currently Logged User Object in the Vue Component. How can I get it? Please give me an answer as soon as possible.

I have tried to pass the User object in the blade file when calling to Vue component as follows and it did not work.

```
<section id="vue-app">
    <add-new-address :userName={{ Auth::user()->name }}></add-new-address>
</section>
```

As well as I used it in Vue component as follows,

```
 props: {
    userName: this.userName ,
  }
```

Retrieved it to input field as follows,

```
<input class="mdc-text-field__input" required="" v-model="userName" name="fname" type="text" >
```

**this is the my vue component**

```
**<template>
  <div class="row" id="addNewtAddress">
          <input class="mdc-text-field__input" required="" id="fname" name="fname" v-model="name" type="text" >
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "AddNewAddress",

  props:['name'],

  data(){
    return{
    }
  }
}
</script>**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `json_encode` and send prop as json object, like this

#### blade

```php
<section id="vue-app">
    <add-new-address name={{ Auth::user()->name }}></add-new-address>
</section>
```

#### vue

```js
props:['name']
```

ref link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: when I am adding userName as you mentioned, It is not showing the vue component in the browser.so, what is wrong with it?

Comment: it does not work for me. when using "name" variable in input I have used like this,  v-model="name". is it wrong?

Comment: used same as you mentioned. but not showing the data

Comment: my devtool is not showing anything. it means devtool is not worked for other methods

Comment: <template>
  <div class="row" id="addNewtAddress">
          <input class="mdc-text-field__input" required="" id="fname" name="fname" v-model="name" type="text" >
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "AddNewAddress",

  props:['name'],

  data(){
    return{
    }
  }
}
</script>

Comment: check the same question. I have edited the question

Comment: i have updated my answer `:name` to `name` try this

Comment: I want to get user name and address as well

Comment: send `user` object and use inside vue and for `user` object you need to do `json_encode()`

Comment: put your code in question and what is not work add there